# Nodejs Paypal api

Tags: javascript, node.js, paypal

So I'm trying to send an api call to Paypal and here is the right way to do it  according to Paypal docs:

```
"items": [
      {
        "name": "hat",
        "description": "Brown hat.",
        "quantity": "5",
        "price": "3",
        "tax": "0.01",
        "sku": "1",
        "currency": "USD"
      },
      {
        "name": "handbag",
        "description": "Black handbag.",
        "quantity": "1",
        "price": "15",
        "tax": "0.02",
        "sku": "product34",
        "currency": "USD"
      }
    ]
```

error received:

```
 { Error: Response Status : 400
 at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Kadiem\node_modules\paypal-rest- 
 sdk\lib\client.js:130:23)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:187:15)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1094:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
response:
{ name: 'VALIDATION_ERROR',
 details: [ [Object] ],
 message: 'Invalid request - see details',
 information_link: 'https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors',
 debug_id: 'b2698c8d3e7a4',
 httpStatusCode: 400 },
 httpStatusCode: 400 }
```

and here is the sent request from Nodejs:

```
router.post('/pay', (req, res) => {
orderid = req.body.orderid;

var products = JSON.parse(req.body.products);

const create_payment_json = {
"intent": "sale",
"payer": {
    "payment_method": "paypal"
},
"redirect_urls": {
  "return_url": "",
  "cancel_url": ""
},
"transactions": [{
    "item_list": {
        "items":

          products.map((product) => {
            return {
              name: product.productname,
              sku: product._id,
              price: product.price,
              currency: "USD",
              quantity: product.quantity
            }
          })

    },
    "amount": {
        "currency": "USD",
        "total": "1.00"
    },
    "description": "Test"
}]
};

paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
 if (error) {
  console.log(error);
   } else {
    for(let i = 0;i < payment.links.length;i++){
     if(payment.links[i].rel === 'approval_url'){
      console.log('Link sent', payment.links[i].href);
      res.json({data: payment.links[i].href});
    }
    }
    }
    });

    });
```

I'm getting error 400 what is it I'm doing wrong here because PayPal internal errors are not clear I can't find out what is the error exactly

Comment: 400 error code indicates a bad request or invalid syntax. So chances are either your JSON payload is malformed, you are missing fields, or the data you are sending is in a bad format. If you can attach the response body and your request body we might be able to help more.

Comment: @Adam I know it means bad request and the problem is in `items` because everything was working until that point

Comment: I'm not familiar with the paypal API. But `.map(...)` will return an array. And in your case it looks like you'll be returning an array within an array; so maybe remove the `[]` around your `products.map` method.

Comment: Remove the `[]` surrounding the products.map() call

Comment: @Adam its an array inside of an array, I posted the right way to do it up from Paypal documentation

Comment: @ThatBrianDude will not work either

Comment: No. What you posted is NOT an array inside an array. It is ONE array containing your products. Your code however is creating TWO arrays. One of them is the array of products which is inside another. Do as we suggested and remove the `[]`

Comment: Can you show the request as well that is producing the 400?

Comment: @AndrewLohr I have added the error, the problem with Paypal apis is they don't show internal errors

Comment: That can be helpful, but I was talking about the code you are using to send the request. Or are you sending the http request some other non-code way?

Comment: @AndrewLohr I have added the request

Comment: for your error print can you try doing `console.log(JSON.stringify(error));`? and share the result. Maybe the details in the error will be more helpful.

Comment: @AndrewLohr OMG thank you the error was the total price thank you so much!!!

Comment: @SimpleWebDesigner no problem, glad to help! Can you write up an answer for your own question? so others that come across this can get some information too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the correct request:

```
    router.post('/pay', (req, res) => {
  orderid = req.body.orderid;

  const products = JSON.parse(req.body.products);
  currency = req.body.currency;
  total = req.body.total;
  subtotal = req.body.subtotal;
  shipping = req.body.shipping;
  tax = req.body.tax;

  const create_payment_json = {
    "intent": "sale",
    "payer": {
        "payment_method": "paypal"
    },
    "redirect_urls": {
      "return_url": "",
      "cancel_url": ""
    },
    "transactions": [{
        "item_list": {
            "items":
              products.map((product) => {
                return {
                  name: product.productname,
                  sku: product._id,
                  price: product.price,
                  currency: "USD",
                  quantity: product.quantity
                }
              }),  
        },
        "amount": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "total": total,
            "details": {
              "subtotal": subtotal,
              "tax": tax,
              "shipping": shipping,
        }
        },
        "description": "Thank you for shopping from us.",
        "invoice_number": orderid,
    }]
};

paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
  if (error) {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
  } else {
      for(let i = 0;i < payment.links.length;i++){
        if(payment.links[i].rel === 'approval_url'){
          res.json({data: payment.links[i].href});
        }
      }
  }
});

});
```

I needed to match the total price of products to the subtotal

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you need to remove the `[]` from your request. You are essentially creating an array (`products.map`) inside an array (`[]`).

Try this:

```
"items": products.map((product) => {
        return {
          name: product.productname,
          sku: product._id,
          price: product.price,
          currency: "AED",
          quantity: product.quantity
        }
      })
```

Comment: Yh I have just noticed it and I removed the `[]` but still not working